# How can I import subpackage?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, package

I have a file structure like this:

```
test.py
Dir1\
  __init__.py
  Something.py
  Dir2\
    __init__.py
    Something2.py
```

```
#Dir1.__init__.py
from .Something import *
```

`Dir2.__init__.py` have has the same code, but with .Something2

Something.py has simple add method, Something2.py has simple sub method.

What I need:

```
#test.py
import Dir1
print(Dir1.Dir2.sub(10, 14))
```

But I get an error `AttributeError: module 'Dir1' has no attribute 'Dir2'`.

If I use `from .Dir2 import *` in `Dir1.__init__.py` code in `test.py` works, but also works `print(Dir1.sub(10, 14))`, what I don't want. I tryed many variants, but they brought me to error or `Dir1.sub` working.

This can probably be found on the Internet, but my knowledge of English is suffering and I may miss the answer. Of course I've already tried searching for it on the Internet.

I will be very grateful for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably it is crutch, but I found solve. Now I have this file structure:

```
test.py
Dir1\
  __init__.py
  Dir1\
    __init__.py
    Something.py
    Dir2\
      __init__.py
      Something2.py
```

```py
#Dir1.__init__
import Dir1 as Add
from .Dir1 import Dir2 as Sub
```

And now I can use

```py
#test.py
import Dir1
print(Dir1.Sub.sub(10, 7))
```

And can't use

```py
#test.py
import Dir1
print(Dir1.sub(10, 7))
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# test.py
import Dir1.Dir2
print(Dir1.Dir2.sub(10,14))
```

Should work. Also if you need to you can rename modules at import using the `as` keyword

```py
import some_module as new_name
```

Comment: Yes, this works, but it turns out that I must ```import Dir1``` and after that ```import Dir1.Dir2```. This is very inconvenient to use and does not work as a whole package.